# Remove default domain from people picker

Tags: sharepoint-server, people-picker

So, I fully understand how to add trusted domains (we have a one way trust with corporate, and can pick from their AD just fine), and have scoured this [document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rajank/2009/09/20/all-you-want-to-know-about-people-picker-in-sharepoint-functionality-configuration-troubleshooting-part-2/) , but I didn't know if there was a way to remove the domain the server is built on from the PP.

Essentially we migrated our users over to corporate AD, but people are still getting confused and adding accounts from the wrong AD environment.

Anyone tried this?

Comment: what do you mean with PP ?

Comment: People Picker, sorry for the shorthand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below command to configure People Picker to only search in a particular AD domain

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -pv "(|(&(mail=*)(userPrincipalName=*domain.com))(objectcategory=group))" -url http://webappurl
```

Comment: So, this seems to work great in dev, but I do have a question as to what the below parameters are doing. 

(&(mail=*) and (objectcategory=group)

Comment: It means import only users which has an email address associated.. just eliminating system users account

Comment: Ok.  So, it worked in our 2010 environment, but not in 2013.  Should it work there as well?